# Dynamically Writing to a List

Tags: c#, .net, list

So I am trying to solve this problem:

> You are given a number n and 2*n numbers. Write a program to check
>   whether the sum of the odd numbers is equal to the sum of the even n
>   numbers. The first number is considered odd, the next even, the next
>   odd again, etc. Print as result “Yes” or “No”. In case of yes, print
>   also the sum. In case of no, print also the difference between the odd
>   and the even sums.
>
> **Input**
>
> The input data should be read from the console.
>
> • The first line holds an integer n – the count of numbers.
>
> • Each of the next 2*n lines holds exactly one number.
>
> The input data will always be valid and in the format described. There
>   is no need to check it explicitly.
>
> **Output**
>
> • The output must be printed on the console.
>
> • Print “Yes, sum=S” where S is the sum of the odd n numbers in case
>   of the sum of the odd n numbers is equal to the sum of the even n
>   numbers.
>
> • Otherwise print “No, diff=D” where D is the difference between the
>   sum of the odd n numbers and the sum of the even n numbers. D should
>   always be a positive number. Constraints
>
> • The number n is integer in range [0...500].
>
> • All other numbers are integers in range [-500 000 ... 500 000].
>
> • Allowed working time for your program: 0.25 seconds.
>
> • Allowed memory: 16 MB."

And my current code, which compiles is this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Odd_and_Even_Sum
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            List<string> stringOfNumbers = new List<string>(2*n);
            stringOfNumbers.DefaultIfEmpty();
            List<int> listOfEvenNumbers = new List<int>(2*n);
            List<int> listOfOddNumbers = new List<int>(2*n);
            int diff = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 2*n; i++)
            {
                stringOfNumbers[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            List<int> listOfNumber = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
            for (int i = 0; i < 2*n; i++)
            {
                listOfNumber[i] = int.Parse(stringOfNumbers[i]);
            }
            foreach (var item in listOfNumber)
            {
                if (IsEven(item))
                {
                    listOfEvenNumbers.Add(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    listOfOddNumbers.Add(item);
                }
            }
            int sumOfEven = listOfEvenNumbers.Sum();
            int sumOfOdd = listOfOddNumbers.Sum();
            if (sumOfEven > sumOfOdd){
                diff = sumOfEven - sumOfOdd;
            }
            if (sumOfEven < sumOfOdd){
                diff = sumOfOdd - sumOfEven;
            }
            if (sumOfEven == sumOfOdd)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Yes, sum ={0}", sumOfEven);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("No, diff={0}", diff);
            }
        }
        public static bool IsEven(int n)
        {
            if (n % 2 == 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My code is compiling, but when I insert the input values I get this errror:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out
>   of range.  Must be non-negative and less than the size of the
>   collection. Parameter name: index    at
>   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.set_Item(Int32 index, T value)    at
>   Odd_and_Even_Sum.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   c:\Users\User1\Documents\V isual Studio 2013\Projects\Odd and Even
>   Sum\Program.cs:line 21

Comment: You never asked us a question, What problem are you having?

Comment: are you allowed to use LINQ?

Comment: when I try to insert the values I get System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException and points at line 21 as the problem

Comment: I suppose I am allowed to use LINQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you write

```
List<string> stringOfNumbers = new List<string>(2*n);
```

you are creating a new **empty** list that have **zero element** but have an **initial capacity bound of 2*n**. It means **it reserves memory for inserting 2*n elements but it does not have any**.

```
stringOfNumbers[i] = Console.ReadLine();
```

here you are trying to access elements of your list which cause exception because there is no element in your list. you should instead use

```
stringOfNumbers.Add(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing the way to a dynamic list elements are added and you have an error in the instance of this list